# How to change this TRUE or FALSE value on run time

Tags: java, android

Here the values want to change true or false by runtime...when some function using time.

```
public static final boolean ENABLE_ADSENSE = true;
```

Comment: there is no possibility to change final value

Comment: As @ArtemBotnev we can't change value of final variable so first remove final word and give more clarification of your question !?!!

Comment: Now i am removed the final.. then how to do that

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is declared with final keyword, its value can’t be modified, essentially, a constant. As if removing final keyword will help you to change the variable value